# How to Navigate Back from Popup in Windows Phone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, popup

here i have this problem with popup window, i popup an usercontrol in a dll and call this dll in an app, but it shows upon a black page that i have no idear where its from. when i push the '<-' button ,the app directly exit... i can't go back to the app's mainpage where calls it.
I wonder how can I return from the popup window. I tried to hide the popup window, but it doesn't go back to app's mainpage.

```cs
public void change_PIN(OnCCB_ChangeUserPINCall changeUserPINCall) 
{
    Popup ppChangePIN = new Popup();
    ChangePIN changePIN = new ChangePIN();
    ppChangePIN.Child = changePIN;
    ppChangePIN.IsOpen = true;
}
```

How can I set `ppChangePIN.IsOpen=false` inside popup window .cs to make it disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle back key press event of back button like

**step1:** first set one flag when popup is open like `**bool PopupOpen=True**`

**step2:** When popup is close at that time **`PopupOpen=False`**

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(PopupOpen== True)
        { 
          ppChangePIN.IsOpen=false;

         PopupOpen=False;
         e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {}
    }
```

If any query let me know...

hope it work for you

Comment: thx for ur reply! but can't find the definition of PopupOpen, is it available in WP8? True u mean true right?

Comment: this is just example you can set one bool flag and do true and false.. when your popup is open at that time flag is true and when your popup is close that time flag is false

Comment: you can do this way if any problem let me know

Comment: ok~i got it, but it still exit directly after i pressed back button.  why is that? is there anything i should do except override OnBackKeyPress?

Comment: when debugger exit OnBackKeyPress ,my app exit and debugger goes into CheckForResetNavigation, then Application_Closing. any idea,  MansinhDodiya?

Comment: what is missing it this `e.Cancel = true;`

Comment: @Enniswen:we are missing e.cancel=true

Comment: @MansinhDodiya SeeSharp,thank u guys, the back button works now!! but how can i return to mainpage when i press a button on the popup window instead of system back button?

Comment: @Enniswen: write navigation code on popup button like navigationService.NavigateTo(new uri("/mainpage.xaml",urikind.absoluteOrRelative);

Comment: @Enniswen: this navigation code is usefull if your are in another page but you are in mainpage than no need to do coding..

Comment: popup window is in a classlibrary, while mainpage is in an windowsphone application, the application references the classlibrary and calls classlibrary's function to show popupwindow in its button_click(i.e). so i cannot use  navigationservice.navigateto() like u said above.

Comment: @Enniswen:okey than what is the proble? when your main page is open  than after on main page one popup is generated than you press back key so popup is close  but main page is remain same in back end

Comment: @Enniswen: ohhh i got your problem ...just do nothing on your popup button write on click of popup  ppChangePIN.IsOpen=false;

         PopupOpen=False;

Comment: @Enniswen: if any query than place comment here

Comment: ppChangePIN is a member of mainpage, not the popupwindow. so i cannot set mainpage.ppChangePIN.IsOpen=false, u got me? that is the difficulty.

Comment: @Enniswen:okey than just do it on click event of button  Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: hi MansinhDodiya, i found a method to do what i want, i'm really appreciate for your help! plus, i solve the problem with EventHandler.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool RemovePopup()
{
   if (ppChangePIN == null || !ppChangePIN.IsOpen) 
      return false;
   ppChangePIN.IsOpen = false;
   return true;
}
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (RemovePopup())
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```